# How to return Struct From Function in C#?

Tags: c#, function, methods, struct, return-value

I defined a struct like this :

```
 public struct Averages
    {
        public decimal Sell_GoldOunce = 0;
        public decimal Buy_GoldOunce = 0;
        public decimal Sell_SilverOunce = 0;
        public decimal Buy_SilverOunce = 0;
        public int Sell_Mazene = 0;
        public int Buy_Mazene = 0;
        public int Sell_Gram_18 = 0;
        public int Buy_Gram_18 = 0;
        public int Sell_Gram_24 = 0;
        public int Buy_Gram_24 = 0;
    };
```

Now i Want to Use it in my Function And Then RETURN IT

```
    public (?) AssignValues()// I WANT TO KNOW WHAT SHOULD I PUT INSTITE OF (?)
    {
        Averages GoldValues;
        GoldValues.Sell_GoldOunce = somevalue;
        GoldValues.Buy_GoldOunce = somevalue;
        GoldValues.Sell_SilverOunce = somevalue;
        GoldValues.Buy_SilverOunce = somevalue;
        GoldValues.Sell_Mazene = somevalue;
        GoldValues.Buy_Mazene = somevalue;
        GoldValues.Sell_Gram_24 = somevalue;
        GoldValues.Buy_Gram_24 = somevalue;
        GoldValues.Sell_Gram_18 = somevalue;
        GoldValues.Buy_Gram_18 = somevalue;

        return GoldValues;
    }
```

as i said i want to know what kind i should define my function to can return struct

Comment: this sounds a lot like a place where you'd have a class..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
public Averages AssignValues()
```

write it, you can return Structs just like classes, but remember that fields in structs are initalized with default values, so your definition of struct should be:

```
public struct Averages
{
    public decimal Sell_GoldOunce;
    public decimal Buy_GoldOunce;
    public decimal Sell_SilverOunce;
    public decimal Buy_SilverOunce;
    public int Sell_Mazene;
    public int Buy_Mazene;
    public int Sell_Gram_18;
    public int Buy_Gram_18;
    public int Sell_Gram_24;
    public int Buy_Gram_24;
};
```

So when you write `Avereges a = new Avereges()` -> `a.Buy_Gram_24` will be 0 because thats int's default value.

Answer (score 9):

Add the name of your struct:

```
public Averages AssignValues()
{
    Averages GoldValues = new Averages();
    GoldValues.Sell_GoldOunce = somevalue;
    GoldValues.Buy_GoldOunce = somevalue;
    GoldValues.Sell_SilverOunce = somevalue;
    GoldValues.Buy_SilverOunce = somevalue;
    GoldValues.Sell_Mazene = somevalue;
    GoldValues.Buy_Mazene = somevalue;
    GoldValues.Sell_Gram_24 = somevalue;
    GoldValues.Buy_Gram_24 = somevalue;
    GoldValues.Sell_Gram_18 = somevalue;
    GoldValues.Buy_Gram_18 = somevalue;

    return GoldValues;
}
```

Comment: maybe `Averages GoldValues = new Averages();`

Comment: I Used 
public Averages AssignValues()
        {
            Averages GoldValues;
            GoldValues.Buy_Gram_18 = 0;

            return GoldValues;
        }

As you said

Comment: That's something else, add in your function : Averages GoldValues = new Averages();

Comment: can you just tell me what is the diffrence between i declare variable like 
Averages G;
or
Averages G=new Averages();